# Paper based on Master Thesis - Disclaimer necessary?

Tags: publications, ethics

Making my Master Thesis into a paper.

I've recently come across a paper that put a disclaimer into the introduction:

`This study is a continuation of work presented in the PhD Thesis ...`.

I wanted to know if such a disclaimer is necessary if my paper is based on my Master Thesis.

Thanks.

Comment: Such disclaimers aren't necessary, but they might appear in the "related work" section to provide additional background. (I would discourage inclusion in the introduction, unless that is where the related work section appears.) If the paper will be co-authored, then such a citation will help distinguish your personal contribution from your contribution in collaboration with others.

Comment: It doesn't seem _necessary_ to me (this may be field dependent), but it seems like there's no harm so it's safest to add a footnote to this effect.

Comment: I do not see a big problem here. However avoid cutting and paste .Really rewrite the paper keeping in mind that it is now a self-standing piece of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is necessary.

Self Plagiarism may seem like a strange thing to be worried about, but there are many reasons to avoid it the way you would any other plagiarism:

- Some journals use double blind reviewing, so reviewers can't distinguish between self-plagiarism and plagiarism.
- You may have received funding for your thesis, which is probably acknowledged in your thesis, but not necessarily in the paper version.
- People reading your paper may want to read the full Master's thesis, since theses generally contain more detail and are less space-constrained than papers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 
Is a full disclaimer necessary or is merely citing the thesis at some point already sufficient? 

Is there some guide online or ethics handbook out there that I could point to for guidance.

Comment: But wouldn't self plagiarism require that the thesis was published? I thought you could only plagiarize published work.

Comment: @morxa I don't see why this is the case. In the general case of plagiarism, if I read something on a blog, or in a colleague's notes, and publish it claiming that it's my own, it is still plagiarism. For a thesis, it's a big more of a grey area as to what "published" means, but most universities keep an archive of all theses completed, so while not peer-reviewed, they are published (in a sense).

Comment: @oldmansaur I'd say that citing is necessary, and a full disclaimer is helpful, albeit not necessary. It will likely put your work into context, which can help potential readers of your paper. I'd view it not as a disclaimer, but as contextualizing the paper in terms of related work.

Comment: I feel like this is another case where it comes down to the field of study. From a chemists point of view: parts of a phd thesis are often published afterwards and I've never seen a disclaimer or anything like that. A PhD thesis, even if published through the university library, doesn't usually count as peer-reviewed article. In addition, it's pretty common that the thesis itself is just a collection of published papers and drafts.